# WatchKit Notification Title Color

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

Is it possible to set the color of the application title (the text that is on a sash). It seems that it is always fixed to white.

In my application I have a light background image with a color that is close to white in the right corner. This makes the name of the app barely readable.

I could not find a way to customize the app title color neither in xCode nor programmatically. It might well be that it is fixed to white. But if anybody changed it, please share the solution!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can click on the arrow of Static Notification in Storyboard.

And in the Attributes Inspector, you can change the Title Color.

---

[image: Screenshot of Notification Arrow]
[image: Screenshot of Storyboard]
[image: Screenshot of Attributes Insepector]

Comment: Thank you very much! Screenshots were very helpful!

Comment: Thank you!! Any way to change the icon to be rectangular and not circle?

Answer (score 0):

You can click on the static notification's notification category in the storyboard  and change the title text colour from the Attributes Inspector.