# How to properly test notifications in a WatchKit app?

Tags: ios, notifications, ios-simulator, uilocalnotification, watchkit

I'm finding some issues regarding showing notifications in the `WatchKit` app:

1) I'd like to see the short-look interface in the simulator, but I don't find how... is it possible?

2) Instead of directly testing the long-look interface by running its related scheme, I'm trying to launch a local notification from the paired iOS app. In the iOS app I'm doing:

```
UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.alertTitle = @"test";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:localNotification];
```

but I run the `WatchKit` app scheme, and I also open the iOS app in the paired iPhone simulator to execute that code snippet, and I see nothing in the Apple Watch simulator...

3) The sash of the long-look interface is supposed to take the color that you set as `global tint` in the storyboard, right? I'm getting it always in the default gray color...

Thanks in advance

Comment: For sash color check this - 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28064963/watchkit-notification-title-color

Comment: 3) to see the sash color on the device, set the notification's category property. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30569308/923288

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) The short-look interface doesn't appear in the simulator, currently. Keep in mind that the simulator isn't working with a full OS simulation like in iOS.

2) Local notifications are not supported in the simulator. You can only test using your schemes and the JSON payload. See this dev forum thread: https://devforums.apple.com/message/1088761#1088761

3) The sash color is set separately, near as I can tell. You can change it in the storyboard.