# WatchKit Notification Sash Color

Tags: ios, watchkit

I've set my notification sash color in storyboard and it works fine in the simulator, but it shows up as gray on my watch. Does anyone know if this is a known issue or do you need to do something at runtime on a real device to show the color properly?
[image]

Comment: Do you set the color while the interface controller is active?

Comment: I am setting it in IB, just like the sample code in watch kit. If you send the notification in watchkit to the simulator it shows up fine. Likewise when I send a push notification to my app, it show up fine in the simulator but on my watch, the sash color is gray, not the color I set it in IB or that shows up in the simulator.

Comment: I also install the update for the Apple Watch today, and the sash colors still show up as gray.

Answer (score 2):

The sash color is set for the WKNotificationCategory in the storyboard, which has a name. (In your screenshot "myCategory"). Then, for the correct sash color to appear on the real device, the push notification needs to have the matching category name when you send it.

```
UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
if (notification) {
    notification.alertBody = @"Hello";
    notification.category = @"myCategory";
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
}
```